# Sending POST request in swift 2

Tags: post, swift2, xcode7

I am making a login app, and when I ever I find a way to send a POST request to php, and I try it, there is either an error, or no errors but does not run my php script. Thanks in advance. I am  using a mac with OS X El Capitan with XCODE 7 and Swift 2. My server is an old windows pc with WAMPServer.

```
    import UIKit
 class Login: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var UserName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var PassWord: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?){
      UserName.resignFirstResponder()
    view.endEditing(true)
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}
   @IBAction func LoginTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    var UserNameEntered = UserName.text
    var PassWordEntered = PassWord.text
    let ClientUserNameStored = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("UserName");
    let ClientPassWordStored = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("PassWord");
    if(ClientUserNameStored != UserNameEntered && PassWordEntered != ClientPassWordStored || ClientUserNameStored != UserNameEntered && PassWordEntered == ClientPassWordStored || ClientUserNameStored == UserNameEntered && ClientPassWordStored != PassWordEntered){
        print("Not equal")
        var Alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "Invalid username or password!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        Alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in UserNameEntered = ""; PassWordEntered = "";
        }))
        presentViewController(Alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else{
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://host/my/file.php")!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "username=\(UserNameEntered)&password=\(PassWordEntered)"
        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            print("response = \(response)")

            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        }
        task.resume()

                  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("GoToHome", sender: self)

    }
}

}
```

My PHP code is below.

```
<?php
$postVar = $_POST['username'];
$postVartwo = $_POST['password'];
$file = fopen("test.txt", "a");
echo fwrite($file, $postVar."pass".$postVartwo);
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: You need to give lots more information if you want an answer.  What error, what code, etc, etc...

Comment: I don't get any errors.

Comment: Then you won't get any answers! :)

Comment: I just added my code.

Comment: What happens when you post data to your php page from a browser?  Set up a form to test your php page and make sure it works.

Comment: when I tested the php in the browser with an html form, the php code is run and does what I want.

Comment: did you put an breakpoint in you NSURLSession response block? Please post the outcoming of the error model and response. And please dont perfrom a seque while the session is running. It will dealloc the controller and than its off

Comment: I did not put a breakpoint at the NSURLSession block, however I did put breakpoints at other areas but I disabled them.

Comment: I did not get any errors, like I said. I got some issues, but not errors, if errors are the red triangular icon with an exclamation mark or dot.

Comment: no we mean a response error :) please put a breakpoint it. Or is the app not starting?

Comment: what is a response error? sorry, i'm new to swift.

Comment: ok i see. When you run the app, make a breakpoint in the session block. Means the blue mark at the left side :) than tap your login, so that the action gets triggered, you should also place a breakpoint in the beginning of the function, to be sure, that the action is triggered. If not, set the action to the button. If yes and your arrived to the response block for your dataRequest than print out the error model that is coming. If you not arrived here, i have no idea what your doing :). Oh and comment out the segue call for testinga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't allow my app to work with HTTP. I changed my info.plist by adding

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Comment: App Transport Security is required for every application submitted to the App Store after 31 December 2016. Opting out of App Transport Security is no longer possible. Note that the App Store review team requires an explanation from you if you partially opt out of App Transport Security by using an exception, such as NSAllowsLocalNetworking or NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent. You can read more about this in Apple's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

After u run the task you perform a seque. this means your leaving the controller and the controller will not exist anymore. There is no strong reference and thats why your response block will not be called.

Remove the performSeque and try again.

Comment: hmm, than put a breakpoint in the response block and check the 3 params in it. The error param would be interesting. Just do in the console : po error